# Understanding special case og Liouville Theorem for subharmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I am trying to understand why the special case of this theorem holds:

> **Liouville Theorem** Let $u$ be a subharmonic function on $\mathbb{C}$ such that \begin{eqnarray} \limsup_{z \to \infty}  \frac{u(z)}{\log |z|} \leq 0.  \end{eqnarray} Then $u$ is constant on $\mathbb{C}$. In particular, every subharmonic function on $\mathbb{C}$ which is bounded above must be constant.

So why does the following implication hold for subharmonic functions?: \begin{eqnarray}  u \, \text{bounded above} \quad \Rightarrow  \quad \limsup_{z \to \infty}  \frac{u(z)}{\log |z|} \leq 0  \end{eqnarray}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That implication holds for any function defined on $\Bbb C$. If
$u(z) \le M$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$ then
$$
\frac{u(z)}{\log |z|} \le \frac{M}{\log |z|}
$$
for $|z| > 1$ and therefore (since $\log |z| \to \infty $)
$$
\limsup_{z \to \infty}  \frac{u(z)}{\log |z|} \le \limsup_{z \to \infty}  \frac{M}{\log |z|} = 0 \, .
$$

In the case of a harmonic function which is bounded above it follows
that the given theorem of Liouville can be applied to conclude that
$u$ is constant.